# Highlight a table column + colspan

Tags: html, css, css-tables

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/KMzjp/

So I am trying to highlight a table column based on a table header `th` element (there are three `th` elements so there should be three columns and the middle one highlighted).

It works without `colspan`s. But when I add colspans to `tbody` (see the second table), it does not work as expected.

See the jsfiddle link to understand my problem better.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `<colgroup>` to the following (adding `span="5"`) would do.

```
<colgroup>
    <col class="" span="5"/>
    <col class="highlight" span="5" />
    <col class="" span="5" />
</colgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

So easy. Good to know col has span attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/FCTjB/